# Booting Ubuntu 14.04.3 - black screen with blinking cursor, then returns ASUS BIOS utility menu

Tags: 14.04, boot, nvidia, uefi, asus

I just built a rig (ASUS X99E WS mobo, intel i7 5930 CPU, MSI GTX 980ti GPU, 2x8 GB G Skill DDR4 2133 RAM) with no OS currently and am having trouble booting Ubuntu 14.04.3 on it. I created the live USB (HP V290W 1638) with Ubuntu using UNetbootin (http://unetbootin.github.io/) but when I try to boot from the EUFI BIOS utility, the screen turns black with the blinking cursor in the top left corner for a few seconds then returns to the BIOS menu. As suggested on a number of forums, I disabled fast boot, disabled secure boot state, made my flash drive the #1 boot option, tried pretty much everything involving the Compatibility Support Module settings (CSM), but nothing seems to have an effect. Anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: can you access the GRUB menu? if so try putting nomodeset as kernel parameter and remove quiet splash to see any error messages https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters

Comment: No, when I hold shift before the opening BIOS screen appears (when I first turn on my computer) to try to enter the GRUB menu, the black screen with the blinking cursor appears for about 10-15 seconds but then the BIOS utility menu loads. Note that the black screen appeared for longer than when I just tried to boot from the flash drive as before.

Comment: It **may** be your hardware is too new for Ubuntu 14.04 - try booting Ubuntu 15.10, or give us more specs on CPU and GPU so we can better guide you. It **may** also be a memory issue: is RAM detected and installed with appropriate timing in BIOS?

Comment: Updated specs. Note, the EUFI BIOS utility does show that it is only recognizing one RAM card, I think. Not sure why. I have them configured on opposite sides of the CPU as instructed in the X99 E WS manual.

Comment: Once your memory issue was resolved you may also have to install with the Intel on-board graphics first. From there you can install the latest proprietary Nvidia drivers that may be needed for your GPU before you switch back to discrete graphics.

Comment: I think one of the RAM cards might be dead. I switched the cards and the computer wouldn't turn on. When I switched them back, it turned on again. I'll have to return them but I should be able to get by with one RAM card to get Ubuntu installed, no?

Comment: Also, do you think it could be the flash drive format? Which one should I have? FAT?

Comment: The USB installation medium is FAT32. Your hard drive needs GPT for the UEFI partition (but you are not yet at this point, unfortunately).

Comment: Are you using a good power supply? I have an Asus z97 and tried older but standard power supply and had memory errors. Microcenter was just able to directly boot with their power supply and nominal fee to show system worked. New power supply solved my issue. Nvidia will be an issue and you need nomodeset on grub or use Intel video as suggested above, UEFI only boot in UEFI settings.

Comment: Try another tool to create the USB flash drive. Although Unetbootin *usually* works, there can be EFI-to-EFI quirks that can cause problems; or you may have made a mistake with Unetbootin. Rufus and `dd` are two other options that usually work. *Do not* enable the CSM (aka "legacy boot support"), since that will either have no effect or create new problems down the line.

Comment: One more thing: Make sure you're using an x86-64/AMD64 version of Ubuntu. The 32-bit (x86, IA32) version will not boot in EFI mode on most 64-bit computers.

Comment: I have a Corsaire 1500. I tried this approach: http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-drive-for-pc-on-a-mac--cms-21187?utm_source=Tuts+&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=relatedtutorials&utm_content=sidebar&WT.mc_id=Tuts+_website_relatedtutorials_sidebar. It worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, I wiped my flash drive and put it in FAT format. Then, I followed this link: http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-drive-for-pc-on-a-mac--cms-21187?utm_source=Tuts+&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=relatedtutorials&utm_content=sidebar&WT.mc_id=Tuts+_website_relatedtutorials_sidebar which worked!